# Optimization in debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have code which runs rather slow, but I know it needs no debugging. I have a third-party hardware attached to my system which works only in debug mode (yeah really, pain in the a%$).

So I wanted to turn the optimization on for my function, but it uses the precisely same time between debug normal mode and optimization turned on.

```
#pragma optimize("ts", on)
void DataAnalyze::PrepareData(std::vector<short>& data, std::vector<short>& laserData, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& normalizedData) {
...
}
#pragma optimize("ts", off)
```

Does that only work in release mode to turn optimization off, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you compile using optimization flags (e.g., equivalent to -O3 in the gcc world) ?

Comment: msvc also has different standard library implementations. So there's an optimized version of `std::` types and and unoptimized one. Try to link to the release version of the runtime. I don't really understand what you mean by " third-party hardware attached to my system which works only in debug mode"

Comment: Usually the debug version of STL has lots of checks turned on. Even if you turn optimisations on for that piece of code, the checks will still be in place and it will be slower than on release.

Comment: I have an oscilloscope attached to my PC that returns 0 only when I run it in release, but proper data in debug mode. No idea why, but that causes the rest of the system to be slow.

Comment: Okay, accessing the members of the vector via short* worked wonders, way faster now. Someone can post that as answer.

Comment: @SinisterMJ you should answer it your self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comments realizing this was caused by STL, I switched to using `short*` instead to access the vector, and that sped up my code by a factor of 3.

Comment: it's probably still non-optimised. you can probably still use vectors outside of that function to make your code safe. the iterators and index operators on vectors are slow in debug, so in your high-performance function, access the data as `short* dataptr = &data[0];` and you get the advantage of vector outside and the speedup of unchecked array indexing in your function. (note: code with optimisation turned on should run 10-1000x faster than debug vectors)